# How to automatically change chat bubble's size?

Tags: swift

I'm using **Swift 3**. I've already made this chat bubbles, but I want it to change sizes...
for example, when there 4 lines of text it's not changing size (making bigger), and I want it to do automatically. How can I do it?

Thank You!

Comment: bubble's size does not depend upon `UITableView` or `UICollectionView`

Answer (score 1):

You need to add constraints in textview/label like this

[image]

Observe constraints of textview selected ,its top, bottom, right, left and Height >= 30 only this will work

and tableview

```
tableview.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0
tableview.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

So it will work like this

[image]

Note: Above label and Date have fixed height. Alternate you can Play with content hugging priority respectives.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
  return estimateFrameForText(text: YourMessageText, width: 280).height + 32
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
  bubbleViewWidthConstraint.constant = estimateFrameForText(text: YourMessageText, width: 280).width + 32
  return cell
}


private func estimateFrameForText(text: String, width: CGFloat) -> CGRect {
    let size = CGSize(width: width, height: 10000)
    let options = NSStringDrawingOptions.usesFontLeading.union(.usesLineFragmentOrigin)
    return NSString(string: text).boundingRect(with: size, options: options, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 13)], context: nil)
}
```

You need to set the font in this code and the font in your UI as same.